# Compile C++ online in a Rails Application

Tags: c++, ruby-on-rails, ruby, compiler-construction

I am looking for a compiler to compile C++ source code in a rails application. My idea is to get the source code as input, compile it and give the output back to the browser. Of course it should be secure and not really forwarded to the system C++ compiler. Is there maybe a ruby library which already do this job?

Best regards,
Fabian

Comment: Not using the "system C++ compiler" has little to do with security.

Comment: So you are looking for a Ruby library which compiles C++ code without system compiler (e.g. g++). In other words you need C++ compiler written in Ruby and packed as Ruby gem. Correct?

Comment: @larsmans that is right but the problem about the system c++ compiler is not the security rather that I am not ensure to have access to this.

Comment: @Greg Dan hmm, yes you're right I should discover the gem repositories...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524814/how-many-unique-c-compilers-are-there

Comment: I did a rails app that does this but insecurely for a school project
https://github.com/acrogenesis/CodeRunner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not the compiler.  You're problem is safely executing the code, which is **VERY** (yes, caps and bold) hard with something as low as C/C++.

In fact, it's almost impossible, your best bet would be a complete sandbox in which the code is going to be executed. There is no ruby library for this AFAIK, and I highly doubt there ever will be one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and I am looking forward to solve this problem :)

Comment: Maybe it exist a web service which executes my code and get result b ack?

Comment: http://codepad.org, though I'm not sure whether you are allowed to use it for applications.

Comment: I was already on this page but I didn't found any kind of an API. But I going to ask the developer of codepad. Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: [This page](http://codepad.org/about) gives a good explanation of how he sandboxed the executions.

Comment: I think the only completely secure way to do this would be with a Virtual Machine. Microsoft's CLR seems the most obvious candidate.

Answer (score 0):

I will try the API[1] of ideone.com

[1] http://ideone.com/api